# Why is mongo driver refuses `$oid` when given `_id` from `json` documents

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have a `json` array with items I want to insert into a mongo collection. I am using it for testing purposes and therefor I *need* a fixed `_id`. The file was extracted from MongoDB Compass.

If this file is used for importing data via Compass, it is behaving normally. Here is a sample of the `books.json`:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "65b2bfd22cf4d67ecf4b24d5"
        },
        "title": "The Name of the Wind",
        "author": "Patrick Rothfuss",
        "pages": 500,
        "rating": 9,
        "genres": [
            "fantasy",
            "magical"
        ],
        "reviews": [
            {
                "author": "Peach",
                "content": "one of my favs"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And here is what I get in Compass (`_id` properly created):

[image: compass result]

When I import the same json file and attempting to `.insertMany`, I am confronted with the following error:

> `Uncaught MongoBulkWriteError MongoBulkWriteError: _id fields may not contain '$'-prefixed fields: $oid is not valid for storage.`

How can I import documents with given `_id` (`ObjectId`) values from a `json` format file?

Could someone offer an explanation for this behavior? Is it intended?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that is closest to my needs is to convert the `json` object into a `js` object (`books.json -> books.js`) and assign the `_id` as:

> `_id: new ObjectId("65b2bfd22cf4d67ecf4b24d5")`

In the end have `books.json` look like this:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export default
[
    {
        _id: new ObjectId("65b2bfd22cf4d67ecf4b24d5"),
        title: "The Name of the Wind",
        author: "Patrick Rothfuss",
        pages: 500,
        rating: 9,
        genres: [
            "fantasy",
            "magical"
        ],
        reviews: [
            {
                author: "Peach",
                content: "one of my favs"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This will work, but it is not a `json` anymore. It would have been useful to use the same file for Compass, for `mongosh` and for `nodejs` driver too.